# How to resolve "Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'problems')" after migrating from Sanity v2 to v3

Tags: javascript, node-modules, vite, sanity

I was updating a sanity project for a client and went through a rather messy Sanity v2 to v3 upgrade (I am not a very experienced developer). I managed to get everything running except now that I "npm run dev" I see an error in the browser after it runs.

```
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'problems')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'problems')
    at http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-JHN2UKAU.js?v=6d449060:92317:106
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at groupProblems (http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-JHN2UKAU.js?v=6d449060:92317:84)
    at createSchema (http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-JHN2UKAU.js?v=6d449060:143733:23)
    at http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-JHN2UKAU.js?v=6d449060:157688:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-JHN2UKAU.js?v=6d449060:157678:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at prepareConfig2 (http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-JHN2UKAU.js?v=6d449060:157675:39)
    at http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-JHN2UKAU.js?v=6d449060:157978:60
```

Doesn't matter that I comment out the schemas and config files, it still pops up the same error

Can someone help please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.